# List of all movie title, actors, directors, writers on Imdb

Tags: movie, imdb, imdbpy

I am working on a web app which lets users tell their favourite movies, directors, movie- writers, and actors. For this I want to provide them a dropdown list or auto complete  for each of them so that they can just pick their choices.

For this: 
I need a list of all movie titles, actors, directors, writers present on Imdb.

I checked Imdbpy and it does not seem to provide methods to get this data.

Would using imdbpy2sql.py to create a database and using sql to query the db, provide the required data? Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Will this be helpful to you? Similar question has been posted in [WebApps stack site](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/free-structured-movie-data-source-where-can-i-find-one)

Comment: @bonCodigo I know of services which give imdb details per movie...they let you retrieve details when you give them movie title or imdb id ...but what I need is a list of all movies on imdb and similarly actors, director and writers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using imdbpy2sql.py to create a database and using SQL to query the db, will provide you the required data.

You can also try using [Java Movie Database](http://www.jmdb.de/) or [imdbdumpimport](https://code.google.com/p/imdbdumpimport/) to read in the text files to SQL.

The last option to do this is parsing the [plain text files](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) provided by IMDb yourself.

Comment: got the data through imdbpy2sql.py + sql queries.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best option is to parse the plain text files distributed here: [imdb interfaces](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces).
You probably just need the 'movies', 'actors', 'actresses' and 'director' file; they are quite easy to parse.

Comment: Were English versions of those databases up at this time? I only see two French and Dutch.. Is this on purpose?

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell: which files are you using? ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/ contains all the English titles, plus a lot of AKAs in other languages.